# CKEditor 5 inline widget -> add space before

Tags: ckeditor5

I wrote and using my custom CKeditor5 plugin. It is an inline-widget according to their docs.
As you see on the screenshot, the widget is directly next to the . of the line before.
Is it somehow possible to add a space before the inline-widget on creation when the previous character is not a space?

I am using `editor.model.change( writer => editor.model.insertContent` to insert the widget.
But from there I have no cursorposition or whatsoever to find out what the previous character is.

[image]